# Придаточное уступительное - "хоть бы"?

Tags: синтаксис

*Плебей всегда плебей, **хоть бы и учился в университете** .*

У меня два вопроса:

а) Выделенное предложение - это придаточное уступки?

б) В каком наклонении стоит глагол в придаточном? Это сослагательное наклонение или *хоть бы* - это одно единство? (стараюсь проверить через "*даже если бы учился в университете*" и думаю, что это сослагательное наклонение, но не уверена на 100%).

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это СПП с придаточным уступительным, причем здесь имеет место **ирреальная (предположительная) уступка**, союз ХОТЯ БЫ (реже ПУСТЬ БЫ, ПУСКАЙ БЫ).

**Частица БЫ** входит в союз и одновременно является показателем сослагательного наклонения.

Пример: Мы его должны разыскать, хотя бы нам пришлось истоптать весь город. [В. Я. Брюсов. Огненный ангел (1908)]